# How to find the largest contiguous, overlapping region in a set of sorted arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Given a tuple of ordered 1D-arrays `(arr1, arr2, arr3, )`, which would be the best way to get a tuple of min/max indices `((min1, max1), (min2, max2), (min3, max3), )` so that the arrays span the largest common range?

What I mean is that

```
min(arr[min1], arr2[min2], arr3[min3]) > max(arr1[min1-1], arr2[min2-1], arr3[min3-1])
```

and

```
max(arr[min1], arr2[min2], arr3[min3]) < min(arr1[min1+1], arr2[min2+1], arr3[min3+1])
```

the same for the upper bounds?

An example:

Given `arange(12)` and `arange(3, 8)`, I want to get `((3,8), (0,6))`, with the goal that `arange(12)[3:8] == arange(3,8)[0:6]`.

**EDIT** Note that the arrays can be float or integer.

Sorry if this is confusing; I cannot find easier words right now. Any help is greatly appreciated!

**EDIT2 / answer** I just realize that I was terrible at formulating my question. I ended up solving what I wanted like this:

```
 mins = [np.min(t) for t in arrays]
 maxs = [np.max(t) for t in arrays]
 lower_bound = np.max(mins)
 upper_bound = np.min(maxs)
 lower_row = [np.searchsorted(arr, lower_bound, side='left') for arr in arrays]
 upper_row = [np.searchsorted(arr, upper_bound, side='right') for arr in arrays]
 result = zip(lower_row, upper_row)
```

However, both answers seem to be valid for the question I asked, so I'm unsure to select only one of them as 'correct' - what should I do?

Comment: ... it is not that you are looking for the largest contiguous, overlapping region in a set of sorted integer arrays, but are unable to word that in plain, simple English?

Comment: almost. it's a set of sorted arrays, mostly float. I updated the question accordingly.

Comment: What do you expect for arange(12, step=2) and arange(3,8)?

Comment: if I understand you right: I would suggest to use 'window' instead of 'range'. You are looking for the largest window for some  relative alignment of the arrays given these two conditions: the numbers in the top row of the window must be larger than ALL numbers above AND smaller than ALL numbers below  + the same vice versa for the bottom row of the window... is that correct?

Comment: @TheodrosZelleke Thanks for your help in formulating my question ;) But now I think you got it mixed. From my understanding, the numbers in the top row must be larger than ALL numbers below AND smaller than ALL numbers above, and vice-versa for the bottom row. Is that what you meant to say? Otherwise, I don't understand what exactly you mean by "top row of the window".

Comment: lets agree on the following: the numbers in edge rows (of the window) should by no means overlap with any adjacent rows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure there are different ways to do this, I would use a [merge](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_algorithm) algorithm to walk through the two arrays, keeping track of overlap regions. If you're not familiar with the idea take a look at [merge-sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort), hopefully between that and the code it's clear how this works.

```
def find_overlap(a, b):
    i = 0
    j = 0
    len_a = len(a)
    len_b = len(b)
    in_overlap = False
    best_count = 0
    best_start = (-1, -1)
    best_end = (-1, -1)

    while i < len_a and j < len_b:

        if a[i] == b[j]:
            if in_overlap:
                # Keep track of the length of the overlapping region
                count += 1
            else:
                # This is a new overlapping region, set count to 1 record start
                in_overlap = True
                count = 1
                start = (i, j)
            # Step indicies
            i += 1
            j += 1
            end = (i, j)
            if count > best_count:
                # Is this the longest overlapping region so far?
                best_count = count
                best_start = start
                best_end = end
        # If not in a an overlapping region, only step one index
        elif a[i] < b[j]:
            in_overlap = False
            i += 1
        elif b[j] < a[i]:
            in_overlap = False
            j += 1
        else:
            # This should never happen
            raise
    # End of loop

    return best_start, best_end
```

Note that end here is returned in python convention so that if `a=[0, 1, 2]` and `b=[0, 1, 4]`, `start=(0, 0)` and `end=(2, 2)`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for a solution to a special case of the [longest common substring problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_substring_problem). While that problem is solvable using suffix trees or dynamic programming, your special case of sorted "strings" is easier to solve.

Here's code that I think will give you the values you want. It's single argument is a sequence of sorted sequences. Its return value is list containing a 2-tuple for each of the inner sequences. The tuple values are slice indexes to the longest common substring between the sequences. Note that if there is no common substring, the tuples will all be `(0,0)`, which will result in empty slices (which I think is correct, since the empty slices will all be equal to each other!).

The code:

```
def longest_common_substring_sorted(sequences):
    l = len(sequences)
    current_indexes = [0]*l
    current_substring_length = 0
    current_substring_starts = [0]*l
    longest_substring_length = 0
    longest_substring_starts = current_substring_starts

    while all(index < len(sequence) for index, sequence
              in zip(current_indexes, sequences)):
        m = min(sequence[index] for index, sequence
                in zip(current_indexes, sequences))
        common = True
        for i in range(l):
            if sequences[i][current_indexes[i]] == m:
                current_indexes[i] += 1
            else:
                common = False

        if common:
            current_substring_length += 1
        else:
            if current_substring_length > longest_substring_length:
                longest_substring_length = current_substring_length
                longest_substring_starts = current_substring_starts
            current_substring_length = 0
            current_substring_starts = list(current_indexes)

    if current_substring_length > longest_substring_length:
        longest_substring_length = current_substring_length
        longest_substring_starts = current_substring_starts

    return [(i, i+longest_substring_length)
            for i in longest_substring_starts]
```

Test output:

```
>>> a=[1,2,3,4,5,6]
>>> b=[1,2,3,5,6,7]
>>> c=[3,4,5,6,7,8]
>>> longest_common_substring_sorted((a,b,c))
[(4, 6), (3, 5), (2, 4)]
```

I'm sorry about not having commented the code very well. The algorithm is somewhat similar to the merge step of a mergesort. Basically, it keeps track of an index into each of the sequences. As it iterates, it increments all of the indexes that correspond to values that are equal to the smallest value. If the current values in all of the lists are equal (to the smallest value, and thus to each other), it knows that it is within a substring common to all of them. When a substring ends, it is checked against the longest substring found so far.